# python copy function by reference

Tags: python, copy

My question is about function callback to be copied by reference

```
func1 = lambda a, b : a+b
func2 = lambda a, b : a*b
ref = func1
ref_ref = ref
ref = func2
print(ref_ref(3,5)) # it returns 8, not 15
```

I wanted to call function with copy by reference(so that the result returns 15) but it didn't work.

How can I get this?

Comment: "copy by reference" is not really standard terminology. You should really explain what you mean more explicitly. Note, there *is no copying going on anywhere in your code*. Python assignment *never copies*.  You should read: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your variable naming, it is kind of obvious what you expected, but thats not the way assignment works in python. After the assignment to `ref_ref` all the variables `func1`, `ref` and `ref_ref`  are actually completely equivalent. `ref_ref` is not a reference to `ref` but directly refers to the same function object, that also `func1` and `ref` refer to. There is no kind of recursive reference involved here.

If you want to achieve the functionality that you expected in your code, you actually need an object, that can lazily resolves a variably name. So you could do

```
func1 = lambda a, b : a+b
func2 = lambda a, b : a*b
ref = func1
ref_ref = lambda : ref
ref = func2
print(ref_ref()(3,5)) # it returns 15
```

Comment: it's exactly what i want for! Thanks a lot.